# Asynchronous ImageCanvas Source

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, openlayers-3

I'm currently using an OpenLayers 3 [ImageCanvas source](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.ImageCanvas.html) with an [Image layer](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Image.html) to render a dynamic layer. I've been working on moving the actual rendering work to a web worker, but I'm running into issues since the ImageCanvas source is really intended for synchronous processing.

The `canvasFunction` is called whenever the viewport changes, and it expects me to return the newly rendered canvas. However, since my rendering is asynchronous, I don't have a newly rendered canvas to return yet. The best I can do is kick off a rendering task and return a blank frame, then trigger OL3 to render again once my worker finishes. Obviously this leads to a flicker effect that is less than ideal.

I noticed that `ol.ImageCanvas` [has some support](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/3935b7db241f47236841616775af0309fd917b0d/src/ol/imagecanvas.js#L16) for asynchronous processing, but it doesn't seem like `ol.source.ImageCanvas` leverages this at all.

Is there some other way that I can leverage this functionality? Or would it be possible to modify `ol.source.ImageCanvas` to do that?

Comment: Note, not certain about specific libraries; are you trying to stream asynchronous content to a `<canvas>` element? Or use `<canvas>` as source for `<img>` element?

Comment: You ever figure this out?  I am looking to do the exact same thing...

Comment: @user163757 yes actually! I made a little add-on for this and just got permission to open source it: https://github.com/ccri/ol3-async-source